# PROMISE(fs.open) is equal to fs.openSync?

Tags: node.js, async-await, fs

is that different between

- `PROMISE(fs.open)` and `fs.openSync`
- `PROMISE(fs.read)` and `fs.readSync`

Comment: What's `PROMISE`?

Comment: @Amadan promisifying `fs.open` just changes the way that callbacks are sequenced after the asynchronous work is done (i.e. until the file is open and a file descriptor is available).  For all intents and purposes, the result works exactly like `fs.open`.  Running `fs.openSync`, on the other hand, will pause all execution of Javascript until that same work is done.  This is undesirable because absolutely no Javascript can run until `fs.openSync` returns a file descriptor.

Comment: Damn...meant to mention OP ( @koner )